# How to share user location from UIActivityViewController in Xcode

Tags: ios, location, share, swift2, uiactivityviewcontroller

I know how to share other objects like images, urls, string or other. But I don't know how can I share from `UIActivityViewController` the current location.
I tried it

```
    @IBAction func sendLocation(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    if mapView.userLocationVisible {
        let currentCoordinate = mapView.userLocation.location!
        print(currentCoordinate)
        let arrayLocation = [currentCoordinate]

        let activityController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: arrayLocation, applicationActivities: nil)
        presentViewController(activityController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else {
        print("User location is not visible")
    }
}
```

But I see in console **<+53.09618071,+49.96449468> +/- 20.00m (speed 0.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 10/11/15, 1:54:26 PM Samara Standard Time**. `UIActivityViewController` doesn't share any location. Please help me.

Comment: You can't simply share a CLLocation - you can share the text that represents the latitude and longitude. You could share an image of a map showing the location...

Comment: I want to make that when send a location, other user will can open this location in map and build the route. @Paulw11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        @IBAction func shareLocation(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
//        print(receivedDictionary)
        let postalAdress = CNMutablePostalAddress()
        postalAdress.street = receivedDictionary["Name"] as! String
        postalAdress.city = receivedDictionary["City"] as! String
        postalAdress.state = receivedDictionary["State"] as! String
        postalAdress.postalCode = receivedDictionary["ZIP"] as! String
        postalAdress.country = receivedDictionary["Country"] as! String
        postalAdress.ISOCountryCode = receivedDictionary["CountryCode"] as! String

        let streetName = receivedDictionary["Name"] as! String

        let urlAddress = receivedDictionary["FormattedAddressLines"] as! [String]
//        print(urlAddress)
        let postalContact = CNLabeledValue(label: streetName, value: postalAdress)
        let urlAddressContact = CNLabeledValue(label: "map url", value: "http://maps.apple.com/maps?address=\(urlAddress.description)")

        let contact = CNMutableContact()
        contact.contactType = .Organization
        contact.organizationName = streetName
        contact.departmentName = streetName
        contact.postalAddresses = [postalContact]
        contact.urlAddresses = [urlAddressContact]

        // create path

        let directory = fileManager.URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)

        let path = directory.first!.path!.stringByAppendingString("/\(streetName).loc.vcf")
//        print(path)

        do {
            let contactData = try CNContactVCardSerialization.dataWithContacts([contact])

            contactData.writeToFile(path, atomically: true)

            let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)
//            print(url)
            let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [url], applicationActivities: nil)
            presentViewController(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } catch {
            print("CNContactVCardSerialization cannot save address")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where did you get the `receivedDictionary`?

Comment: @oyalhi in other class

Comment: I figured yes, it seems like a vital part of the function though. What I ended up doing was calling the http directly and it would open the related app if installed if not it would open the related web page.  `let googleString = "https://www.google.com/maps/place/Starbucks/@32.6864286,-117.1821824,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x80deacc97a19561b:0xf12ab2d5340288f2"
        
        if let URL = NSURL(string: googleString) {
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(URL)
        }` Good enough for my case for now. The googleString is direct copy from the web page.

Comment: @oyalhi I understood you